# Como corrigir o erro "SQLException: No suitable driver found" ao realizar uma conexão?

Tags: java, mysql, conexão

Estou tentando realizar a conexão com o banco de dados em meu código, entretanto ele aparece o seguinte erro:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: 
>   No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usuario

Código:

```
public class ConexaoBd {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException{
        Connection conexao = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usuario","root","tonhaoroot");

        conexao.close();    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Antes de criar a conexão você precisa registrar o driver do mysql. Vai ficar assim:

```
public class ConexaoBd {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); /* Aqui registra */
        Connection conexao = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usuario","root","tonhaoroot");

        conexao.close();    
    }
}
```

Também verifique se o driver mysql(.jar) se encontra no classpath da aplicação.

Comment: Hummm, pensei mesmo que tinha algo a ver com drive mysql. Vou testar aqui cara. Já aviso se funcionou.

Comment: Estou fazendo no VS Code, no caso o classpath da aplicação no meu caso seria aonde? Eu coloquei o jar do driver dentro de "Referenced Libraries".

Comment: O classpath é aonde ficam as libs do java no servidor. JBoss tem uma pasta tomcat tem outra. Essas libs ficam disponiveis para para obter instancias em runtime.

Answer (score -5):

No seu arquivo .properties, vc precisa retirar as aspas do valor da chave.

ficaria assim:
**banco.url**=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/curso_java?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true
**banco.usuario**=root
**banco.senha**=pc1989

Comment: Olá Luiz, boas-vindas ao site. Note que a pergunta é de [2015](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/88922/timeline#history_d1f24835-d8d7-4d60-8c9f-3724f1ff4c07), e já foi [respondida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/88929/3635), o que indica que o problema não tem haver com o .properties. É legal tentar ajudar, mas recomendo que entenda primeiro o funcionamento do site fazendo o [tour] e principalmente lendo o [FAQ da comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/3635). Obrigado por compreender.